# Pandas: Reshape two columns into one row

Tags: python, pandas, pivot

I want to reshape a pandas DataFrame from two columns into one row:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df_a = pd.DataFrame({ 'Type': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'], 'Values':[2,4,7,9,3]})
df_a

   Type Values
0   A   2
1   B   4
2   C   7
3   D   9
4   E   3

df_b = df_a.pivot(columns='Type', values='Values')
df_b
```

Which gives me this:

```
Type A       B       C       D      E
0   2.0     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
1   NaN     4.0     NaN     NaN     NaN
2   NaN     NaN     7.0     NaN     NaN
3   NaN     NaN     NaN     9.0     NaN
4   NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     3.0
```

When I want it condensed into a single row like this:

```
Type A       B       C       D      E
0   2.0     4.0     7.0     9.0     3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you dont need `pivot`, better is `DataFrame` constructor only:

```
df_b = pd.DataFrame([df_a['Values'].values], columns=df_a['Type'].values)
print (df_b)
   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  4  7  9  3
```

Or [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with transpose by `T`:

```
df_b = df_a.set_index('Type').T.rename({'Values':0})
print (df_b)
Type  A  B  C  D  E
0     2  4  7  9  3
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought there would be a simple solution and there was.

Answer (score 0):

Another way:

```
df_a['col'] = 0
df_a.set_index(['col','Type'])['Values'].unstack().reset_index().drop('col', axis=1)

Type    A   B   C   D   E
  0     2   4   7   9   3
```

Answer (score 0):

We can fix your df_b

```
df_b.ffill().iloc[[-1],:]
Out[360]: 
Type    A    B    C    D    E
4     2.0  4.0  7.0  9.0  3.0
```

Or we do

```
df_a.assign(key=[0]*len(df_a)).pivot(columns='Type', values='Values',index='key')
Out[366]: 
Type  A  B  C  D  E
key                
0     2  4  7  9  3
```